If implicit differentiation yields an undefined expression at a point. Does this mean that derivative is undefined at that point?
Equation $(x-y)^2=0$ implicitly defines two functions: $y=x$. The derivative of each is 1. But the implicit differentiation yields the expression that not defined at $y=x$:
$$(x-y)^2=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}( x-y)^{2} =\frac{d}{dx} 0$$
$$2(x-y)\frac{d}{dx}(x-y) =0$$
$$(x-y)\frac{d}{dx}(x-y) =0$$
$$(x-y)\left(\frac{d}{dx} x-\frac{dy}{dx}\right) =0$$
$$(x-y)\left(1-\frac{dy}{dx}\right) =0$$
$$(x-y) -(x-y)\frac{dy}{dx} =0$$
$$(x-y)\frac{dy}{dx}=(x-y)$$
If $x-y\neq 0$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x-y}{x-y}=1$$
So in each point $y=x$, the expression $\frac{x-y}{x-y}$ is undefined, due to zero devision, while in all others it gives 1
Is it correct to answer 'no' to the question posed? Even if implicit differentiation yields an undefined expression at a point, the derivative may still exist?
Update
Perhaps, this case is related to implicit function theorem (IFT).
If all conditions of IFT hold, then implicit function must exist. But in this case $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x-y)^2=2(x-y)$ is zero in all points $x=y$. So IFT do not say anything about implicit function existence in the relation $(x-y)^2=0$ and its differentiability

Since $x$ and $y$ are independant, you should treat $y$ as a constant when differentiating with respect to $x$

In this case, the answer is no because you used an intermediate form of the derivative expression $\left(\frac{x-y}{x-y}\right)$. As you showed, fully simplifying this would yield $1$, which is the form of the derivative we should use. And we know this is the right approach because the graph of the function $(x-y)^2=0$ clearly has a slope of $1$ for all points; $x$ must equal to $y$ for the equation to be true, so they change with a $1:1$ ratio.
